# How do I select on a joined table in Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```sql
SELECT * FROM messages
    INNER JOIN posts ON messages.ad_id = posts.id
WHERE posts.user_id = 1;
```

I have the above query, but I'm not sure how to do it with the Eloquent ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = Message::join('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'messages.ad_id')
    ->where('posts.user_id', 1)
    ->select('messages.*','posts.*')
    ->get();
```

You have examples in laravel docs, hope they help you :D
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins

Answer (score 0):

Hi perhaps use the `join` method:

```
$messages = DB::table('messages')
    ->select('*')
    ->join('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'messages.ad_id')
    ->where('posts.user_id', 1)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Can this be done while returning the model objects?